# Separability of kernel of compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

If $T$ is a compact operator in a Hilbert space, then its range is separable since is a set with compact closure. But what can I say about the $\mbox{ker}(T)$ set? Is it also separable? If so, what is the argument to prove it?

I've tried to observe this by projecting $\overline{\mbox{range} (T)}$ over $\mbox{ker}(T)$, but I can't figure out how to build a dense sequence in $\mbox{ker}(T)$, so I don't know if the result is true or false

Comment: The zero operator is compact and its kernel is the whole space.

Comment: Just as a note for future reference, but no the range of a nonzero linear operator cannot have a compact closure since it is a *subspace* hence in particular unbounded...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course if the Hilbert space $H$ is separable then the kernel of $T$ is automatically separable.  But if $H$ is not separable then $\operatorname{ker} T$ is *never* separable.

For example, the adjoint $T^*$ is also compact, and the orthogonal complement of its image (which is separable) is the kernel of $T$.  If the kernel of $T$ were separable then we would have $H$ as the direct sum of two separable subspaces.

Comment: Thanks got it :)